# @media min and max both or just one

Tags: performance, css, responsive-design, media-queries, width

For example, use both

`@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){...}
@media (max-width: 768px) {...}`

or just

`@media (max-width: 992px) {...}
@media (max-width: 768px) {...}`

What's more efficient? I want browser performance!

To width less then 768px in the second case the browser will apply the *style* two times until get the correct one?

Comment: Well for me they are just the same, just that the second will be in lesser size than the first one

Answer (score 1):

Use this one

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){...}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {...}
```

In this way browser not apply same css two times and you can easily use css with different property in different devices size. 
Sometimes browser don't overwrite the css in different device media query then you use `!important` in css.

**Example**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px){
 .nav{max-width:900px;}
}
@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px){
 .nav{max-width:700px !important;}
 // only use important if browser not apply this property in this device size
}
```